# Elasticsearch - Research that returns too many bad results

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I have an elasticsearch that works but it is really too large, it gives me too many results on terms that have nothing to do with it. I'm looking for a way to refine these results.

On a sample of fake text when I search for the term `music`, the terms that come out in highlights are :
`must, much, alice, inside, patriotic, noticed`

I think that the `ngram` doesn't help me but I think I really need it to have a better search.

Here is my configuration :

```json
{
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "default": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": ["lowercase", "mySnowball", "myNgram"]
            },
            "default_search": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "mySnowball", "myNgram"]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "mySnowball": {
                "type": "snowball",
                "language": "English"
            },
            "myNgram": {
                "type": "ngram",
                "min_gram": 2,
                "max_gram": 6
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my request :

```json
    {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "match": {
                    "content": "music"
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "url": "music"
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "h1": "music"
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "h2": "music"
                }
            }
         ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    },
    "min_score": 8
}
```

My document is quite simple :

```
content => text,
url => text,
h1 => text,
h2 => text,
```

And the mapping too:

```php
$configMapping  = [
    'content' => ['type' => 'text', 'boost' => 6],
    'url'     => ['type' => 'text', 'boost' => 6],
    'h1'      => ['type' => 'text', 'boost' => 9],
    'h2'      => ['type' => 'text', 'boost' => 7]
]
```

I welcome any modification that will allow me to obtain only consistent results.

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Answer (score 1):

As you said yourself, analyzing with 'ngram' is the reason you get all these unrelated results.

In all the results you get, you can see the token (2 characters token, as the minimum of your n-gram) that matched the query term 'music':
***mu**st, **mu**ch, al***ic**e, in**si**de, patriot**ic**, not**ic**ed

Start by removing this filter from your analyzer and keep on tuning the results from there.

Comment: this is what I did to remove the problem temporarily, I use a search with exact terms for the moment.
I will replace the Google search engine another time^^